# Cannot connect to RDS SQL Server Database using Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssms, amazon-rds

I created a SQL Server RDS Instance in AWS and it seems to be up and running, but if I try to connect to it using Management Studio I get this error:
[image]

Here is the text of the error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

I initially tried with the default security group that was created with the instance, but when that didn't work I created a new security group and modified the instance to use it.

Here you can see the details:
[image]

I tried this connection setup to connect:
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name:  valuationdlsdev.ck1qvjqhglyg.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Login: the Master User Login I created when creating the RDS Instance
Password: the Master User Password I created when creating the RDS Instance

I was kinda at my wits end and so I changed the setting on the Security Group to All traffic just to see if that would work, so here are all the settings on the security group:[image]

At this point I'm wondering if port 1433 is not open, because I feel like I've tried everything. Could someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: This instance was created using SQL Server SE 2016.  When I created one using the SQL Server Express version I was able to connect, but not with SE.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this post looking for an answer, I just wanted to updated and make sure it's there if anyone needs it.  The issue here turned out to be that I misunderstood the way "Publicly Accessible" works and set it to "Yes".  Apparently it should have been set to "No".  "Yes", however does work for the SQL Server Express version.

Answer (score 18):

In my case I opened the VPC Security group associated with my database

[image]

In the EC2 Security groups dashboard I selected Edit Inbound Rules from the actions dropdown and chose edit inbound rules.

At first, I looked at the inbound rules and thought everything was OK since this was the current setup
[image]

After all - if it was allowing all traffic, then what could possibly be wrong?

On a whim I added a rule for TCP port 1433. Ending up with this simple setup

[image]

Then it immediately started working for me.

Comment: I have all of this perfectly done, but still not able to connect. With same sg and vpc and subnets and everything same, postgre db instance I am able to connect, but only with mssql cannot connect

Comment: Awesome! worked for me. I had `All traffic` source as `sg-xxxxx` and I replaced it with `0.0.0.0/0` and then added the `MSSQL` rule as mentioned above.

Comment: This worked for me too, when I checked it, it had a static IP in there, I deleted that and replaced it with the 0.0.0.0/0 (looks like above) and it works.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure it is publicly accessible, there is a radio button you have to check to make it publicly accessible.[image]

Also add MS SQL inbound rule in inbound tab.After making the change wait for sometime so that the settings are updated in the instance.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this was counter-intuitive. With the options I selected, all ports and IPs seemed to be open, but after editing the inbound and outbound rules in the security group to have MS SQL for anywhere, I was able to connect.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

I ended up deleting the security group inbound rules, and just added a new inbound rule for port 1433, source being: 0.0.0.0

Image attached.

[inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4MpV.png)

Comment: Saviour!! This helped me after struggling for 2 hours :)

Answer (score 2):

For inbound rules, go to the VPC Security group of your database instance

In Inbound tab click modify

In column source change ip 0.0.0.0 by your IP by "My IP" or "Anywhere"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the discussion here. Just post my finding in case anyone needs help in the future.

I initially followed this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html.

then, I got some ideas from this post and figure out my particular issue in the end. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=845682 The poster really did wonderful troubleshooting steps which could help fix most of the general Error 258 problems already. In the end I used the suggestion from the answerer to find out my problem.

In terms of my case of encountering error 258, I tried to connect to RDS SQL server 2016 inside a secure network from my workplace. When I switched to use the public network served by some Telecomm vendor, the connecting was succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from different network were the instance was created, you'll need to open access to the IP range of where you want to access, by going to the "security group" assigned to your DB instance, and then adding the rule for your IP range.

PD. AWS by default only allow access from the IP range of the machine where you activated "public access" to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was also not able to access it from my office laptop, but I was able to access it from my personal laptop. I think it is because of some company firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same issue, though this post helped me understand the issue and I added an inbound rule to the VPN security group for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 instead using 0.0.0.0/0 to keep it limited to be accessible from my network only.

Here xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 is my network/organization external IP address /32 is used for IPV4. If you don't know your external IP, it can be found using "what's my IP" on google from any computer within the network.

0.0.0.0/0 allows inbound traffic from all IPs across internet which could be unsafe.